# Selbständig vs. selbstständig

Tags: difference

*Selbständig* and *selbstständig* seem to share the same meaning. What are the differences in tone and usage?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Selbständig" is the traditional orthography of the word (double "st" was collapsed). It also resembles the pronunciation more closely, since saying a double "st" is hard, even for a German.

"Selbstständig" is the more modern variant that is allowed since the orthography reform. It is also the "more logical" variant, since it really is a composite adjective consisting of *selbst* and *ständig*.

Comment: You have an st /zt/ in the first syllable, while in the second you have an st which is spoken like scht. IMHO, it is easy to speak it like selbstständig, although the difference vanishes when spoken quickly.

Comment: When I speak it, it becomes "selb-schtändig" - without a sharp `st` at all. Pronunciation leans towards the way of least resistance. ;)

Comment: What if I pronounce the first *s*, but not the middle *t*? ;)

Comment: Seit wann hat Sprache logisch zu sein? Ich finde übrigens *selbstständig* absolut nicht logisch.

Comment: For one thing, this is not about language but about orthography. And for another thing, both need to be logical, or they don't make sense (duh). One can always define an exception, but for that, there still needs to be a *rule*.

Answer (score 17):

Simple:

- selbständig: spelling according to the old orthography ("Alte Rechtschreibung")
- selbstständig: alternative spelling according to the new orthography ("Neue deutsche Rechtschreibung")

These are just two ways to spell the same word. There is no difference in tone or usage.

Both spelling are considered correct since the new orthography was introduced.

Comment: @björn You are right. I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer**
*selbständig* and *selbstständig* are two words with different pronunciation but no difference in tone or meaning whatsoever.

---

**Long answer** (also addressing some questions, that were only asked in a „duplicate“ of this question)

**First** of all, there are two possible origins of this words: *selbst* + *ständig* and *selb + ständig.*
The latter uses the particle *selb* which is also used in other German words like *selber* or *selbst.*
It is most probably impossible to tell which of these two is older.

**Secondly,** despite many people considering this a spelling issue, it is not.
For non-loanwords, like *selbständig,* **all** German orthographies (from new spelling over failed spelling reforms to very old spelling) are mainly phonetic and only operate within a certain range of tolerance, such that the following holds (taking into account all orthographies at once):
A given spelt word may only represent a very limited number of spoken words and vice versa, e.g., *Maß* may only represent the pronunciations [mas] and [maːs], and [maːs] may only be spelt with *maß, mass, masz, mas, mahs, maas, maahß* or other combinations of the elements used therein (ignoring capitalisation).

So, unless an orthography chooses to ignore several major spelling paradigms for this single case only (see below), there is no way that the two pronounced words [ˈzɛlp**ʃt**ɛndɪç] and [ˈzɛlp**stʃt**ɛndɪç] are represented by the same spelling.
Also, the other way round, any non-sloppy pronunciation of *selbstständig* has to contain at least two more phonemes than for *selbständig.*
Admittedly, [ˈzɛlp**stʃt**ɛndɪç] may be reduced to [ˈzɛlp**ʃt**ɛndɪç] without the speaker noticing, but the same also holds for some other words or pairs of words like *Schwellenwert/Schwellwert,* the difference between which nobody would consider a spelling issue.
(Note that one still might consider such differences an issue of style.)

Another argument for are constructions, where the words are decomposed:

> selb- und eigenständig
>   selbst- und eigenständig

Here, there is a clear difference in pronunciation and I do not think that anybody would consider the difference between the two a spelling issue.

However, over some decades prior to 1996, the Duden dictionary was the official orthographical authority and therefore it could declare single-word rules and indeed did (sort of):

> **selbständig:** Das Adjektiv *selbständig* ist mit dem Stamm des Pronomens *selbst,* also mit *selb-* gebildet. Die heute allein gültige Schreibweise des Wortes ist daher die mit einem -st- (Silbentrennung: *selb-ständig*). (Duden Bd. 9, 1985, quote according to [Ickler](http://www.sok.ch/files/Ickler_FDS_14jun05_selbststaendig_Putativgehorsam.pdf))

However, one can still argue that, even then, *selbstständig* was orthographically correct, since a German speaker could create a new word *selbstständig* as a composite of *selbst* and *ständig* impromptu, which is not addressed by the above quote and therefore orthographically correct (just as one can create the orthographically correct word *Hundekotbeutelspender* impromptu).
Also, one could argue that this is not an orthography issue and therefore was not under the “jurisdiction” of the Duden’s orthographical authority (or any other orthography).

With the orthography reform of 1996, the Duden’s questionable single-word rule was not adopted, so there is no orthographical argument against either word anymore.
It should be noted, that the current spelling rules use *selbständig* and the Duden’s position regarding *selbständig* was criticised also by Theodor Ickler, a prominent opponent of the orthography reforms of 1996 and 2006.

**Finally,** which variant is preferable? Historically and etymologically, both are justified, and neither variant is more logical or orthographically preferable (see above).
*Selbständig* is easier to pronounce and hence most probably the dominant word in spoken language.
One might also consider it to be easier to read.
*Selbstständig* on the other hand is more consistent with other words beginning with *selbst,* such as *selbsttätig, selbstredend* or *selbstvergessen.*

**References and further reading:**
  http://www.sok.ch/files/Ickler_FDS_14jun05_selbststaendig_Putativgehorsam.pdf
  http://sok.ch/2008/12/selbstandigselbststandig/
  http://www.keinekuhhaut.de/2010/11/10/selbstaendig-oder-selbststaendig/

Comment: Mackensen (35. Aufl., 1960): nur _selbständig_. Wahrig (1996): "Die richtige Schreibweise lautet _selbstständig_, die alte Schreibung ... bleibt aber weiterhin zulässig." Wahrig (2006): "Es bleibt den Schreibenden überlassen, ob sie die gekürzte Form _selbständig_ oder die Vollform ... bevorzugen: _selbstständig_."

Answer (score 8):

There's no difference. Both are one and the same word, and there's also no difference in tonation. But "selbstständig" is the preffered way to use.
As you can see in the "[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/selbststaendig/)", "selbständig" is just an alternative form for the word.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wasn't referring to the pronunciation, but to the connotations that the word carries.

Answer (score 7):

I think *selbständig* was the correct form until the spelling reform. Since then you can use both.

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference in the usage of those words. In fact, they are different spellings of the same word.

This seems to be a case of simplification of a word, that's combined of two other words (*selbst* and *ständig*). The combination is a bit difficult to write and pronounce. So the colloquial just "merges" both *st* and this has also been transfered to the written language – both are valid spellings.